# How to add & remove column in admin > sales > orders

Tags: magento

i have to remove Bill to Name column & add two new columns product title name (which describe the product Name of Product) & Payment Method(which describe the payment method at the time of order in admin > sales > orders [image]

Answer (score 0):

first you will go to the this file:

.../app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php

and remove this content:

```
    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));
    add two field in same grid table
```

and add this content:

```
    $this->addColumn('DBfieldname', array(
        'header' => 'header name',
        'index' => 'cantroller get params name',
    ));
```

it's same content add two times it will be generated to two field.
cantroller get params like in add data cantroller:

```
'DBfieldname' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('cantroller get params name')
```

it same procase in edit cantroller olso.
get data product collection in cantroller and get product name of product. 
Payment Method olso get params in this collection.